# Laravel - Get returned data from an API within the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have an API `/getuser` which returns a reponse along with the user object:

```
$user = session()->get('current_user');
return response()->json(['user'=>$user]);
```

Now, I want to get the said returned api within my function `public function show_user()`.

I tried `$current_user = return redirect('/getuser');` but it's giving me an error - I don't know why specifically but I'm pretty sure you can't assign a returned response on a variable perhaps?

Reason why I'm using a different API on getting the user is because of Sessions. The `api routes` cannot read/store sessions properly (probably because they're stateless or something) so I placed that `/getuser` on the `web routes` which works perfectly. I could call the web "api" anywhere and it would give me the current user. Now however, I cannot reference the said current user within the `api routes` by doing `session()->get()...` since it wouldn't read sessions. My solution is to call that `/getuser` api I made on `web routes` and assign its returned response on a variable - which I have no idea how.

Is there anyway I could achieve something like that?
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use guzzle in laravel when you need to call api in your controller.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class MyController extends Controller {

    public function show_user()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', '/getuser', [
            'form_params' => [
                'KEY' => 'VALUE',
            ]
        ]);

        $result= $res->getBody();
        dd($result);

}
```

Read blog [here](https://medium.com/laravel-5-the-right-way/using-guzzlehttp-with-laravel-1dbea1f633da)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It gives me this error: `cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

Comment: Which points to this: `? new ConnectException($message, $easy->request, null, $ctx)
            : new RequestException($message, $easy->request, $easy->response, null, $ctx);
 `

Comment: @devReb did you follow instruction in the blog post?

Comment: Thanks for this. I managed to solved it by using web routes. I will keep this method  as well for future purposes if ever I need to use it. God bless! =)

Comment: @devReb glad it help